# "Failed to determine Process ID" when running apache nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

```
C:\nifi-1.24.0\bin>run-nifi.bat
2023-12-25 16:01:27,941 
INFO [main] 
org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Generating Self-Signed Certificate: 
Expires on 2024-02-23

2023-12-25 16:01:29,114 
INFO [main] 
org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command 
Generated Self-Signed Certificate SHA-256: 
946BCE58238C4B91808CA2DC4E71236F11B38FB1EC85B77D8D1141816CC03C24

2023-12-25 16:01:29,134 
INFO [main] 
org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Starting Apache NiFi...

2023-12-25 16:01:29,134 
INFO [main] 
org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Working Directory: 
C:\NIFI-1~1.0

2023-12-25 16:01:29,134 
INFO [main] 
org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Command: 
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\bin\java.exe 
-classpath 
C:\NIFI-1~1.0\.\conf;
C:\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar;
C:\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\jcl-over-slf4j-2.0.9.jar;
C:\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\jetty-schemas-5.2.jar;
C:\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\jul-to-slf4j-2.0.9.jar;
C:\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\log4j-over-slf4j-2.0.9.jar;
C:\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\logback-classic-1.3.11.jar;
C:\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\logback-core-1.3.11.jar;
C:\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\nifi-api-1.24.0.jar;
C:\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\nifi-framework-api-1.24.0.jar;
C:\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\nifi-nar-utils-1.24.0.jar;
C:\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\nifi-per-process-group-logging-1.24.0.jar;
C:\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\nifi-properties-1.24.0.jar;
C:\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\nifi-property-utils-1.24.0.jar;
C:\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\nifi-runtime-1.24.0.jar;
C:\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\nifi-server-api-1.24.0.jar;
C:\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\nifi-stateless-api-1.24.0.jar;
C:\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\nifi-stateless-bootstrap-1.24.0.jar;
C:\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\slf4j-api-2.0.9.jar 
-Dorg.apache.jasper.compiler.disablejsr199=true 
-Xmx1g -Xms1g 
-Dcurator-log-only-first-connection-issue-as-error-level=true 
-Djavax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly=true 
-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/urandom 
-Dzookeeper.admin.enableServer=false 
-Dsun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders=true 
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true 
-Djava.awt.headless=true 
-Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=sun.net.www.protocol 
-Dnifi.properties.file.path=C:\NIFI-1~1.0\.\conf\nifi.properties 
-Dnifi.bootstrap.listen.port=49744 
-Dapp=NiFi 
-Dorg.apache.nifi.bootstrap.config.log.dir=C:\NIFI-1~1.0\bin\..\\logs org.apache.nifi.NiFi

2023-12-25 16:01:29,144 
INFO [main] 
org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command 
Failed to determine Process ID from [java.lang.ProcessImpl]: 
java.lang.Process.pid()

2023-12-25 16:01:29,144 
WARN [main] 
org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command
```

Launched Apache NiFi but could not determine the Process ID.

I tried deleting all the repositories created in nifi folder, but the same error still persists.